# Is it possible to customize JupyterLab main menu to route another page?

Tags: javascript, jupyter-lab

I have been messing around JupyterLab UI. It seems like I could have added some custom menus.

Just like the repository's very first picture below:

https://github.com/jupyterlab/extension-examples/tree/master/main-menu

However I want to make it just like any other websites top navigation menu - when clicking each menu it redirects to another page instead of windows-app-like-menu.

In, `packages\mainmenu-extension\src\index.ts` I found out below:

```
 commands.addCommand(CommandIDs.logout, {
    label: trans.__('Log Out'),
    caption: trans.__('Log out of JupyterLab'),
    execute: () => {
      router.navigate('/logout', { hard: true });
    }
  });
```

The router logic above depends on dropdown menu because of `commands.addCommand` as I understand and I do not want to implement like that... so I tried take `router.navigate('/overview', { hard: true });` and put it into like below:

```
export function createOverviewMenu(
  app: JupyterFrontEnd,
  menu: OverviewMenu,
  router: IRouter,
  trans: TranslationBundle
): void {
  menu.menu.title.label = trans.__('Overview');
  router.navigate('/overview', { hard: true });
}
```

but no luck, because it runs all the createMenu functions when app executes so that as soon as the app launched it automatically redirects to `/overview` no matter I click the `overview` menu or not.

Now I am messing around some sort of onClick functions that were already implemented but no one is related to that menus. I have also tried `handleEvent` from this doc below:

https://jupyterlab.github.io/lumino/widgets/classes/menu.html

but it is not working.

Is there onClick function which invokes when clicking the each menu? or is it even possible to implement, customize that way?

Comment: This is a good question, but I don't think that this is a good UX. Users would be very surprised to see that opening top-level menu item actually opens a new tab (or browser if they are running JupyterLab as a standalone app). There are workarounds I could think of (create a command attached to this menu and modify its `isVisible` callback; once it is called open a new tab) but I would strongly advise against abusing the UI this way. Instead I would recommend adding a custom button at the same place where the top menu is located (e.g. to the right) but visually distinct.

Comment: See this extension for an example of placement of a custom button on the same level as the menu: https://github.com/jtpio/jupyterlab-theme-toggle